# Haskell : Applicative Functor

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell. I've made a type Maybe3.

```
data Maybe3 a= Just3 a| Unknown3 | Missing3 deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)
eq3 :: Eq a => Maybe3 a-> Maybe3 a-> Bool3
eq3 Unknown3 _ = Unk3
eq3 Missing3 _ = False3
eq3 _ Missing3 = False3
eq3 _ Unknown3 = Unk3 
eq3 (Just3 a) (Just3 b)=if a==b then True3 else False3
```

How to make Maybe3 an applicative functor? And how to make it a Monad?

Comment: Your best bet would be to read how Maybe is an Applicative functor and a Monad, and generalise them to your Maybe3 type.

Comment: Observe that `Maybe3 a` is isomorphic to `Either Bool a`, perhaps that can guide you a bit. Otherwise, how about showing something you have tried, so as to see where you're experiencing problems? At least the `Functor` instance is really simple, as usual.

Comment: it is not an `Applicative` in a unique way.  I think there is only one way to make it a monad, but have not proven this fact.

Comment: @PhilipJF You have to use an essentially monoid structure on the `Bool` part of leftaroundabout's isomorphism, but `Bool` is a monoid in two ways, one with `&&` and one with `||`. This means we can make it a Monad in two ways, one for each of the two answers for what `Unknown3 <> Missing3` is. Unfortunately the order of equations in the `Eq` instance suggests that `<>` mightn't be commutative, which I believe would lead to problems with the associative law for monads, but if I'm wrong in that would make two further possible instances.

Comment: @PhilipJF By the way, the "You need a monoid structure on Bool" reasoning popped straight in my head because I read the fantastic Comonad Reader article, [Abstracting with Applicatives](http://comonad.com/reader/2012/abstracting-with-applicatives/) which felt like coming across monad transformers for the first time, but for applicatives, (therefore nicer and less full of `<-`). I feel it's an article worth advertising, so have taken this opportunity.

Comment: Proof that it is only a monad in one way:

`Left x >>= return = Left x` and therefore `Left x >>= f = Left x` since you can't pattern match on functions.  Thus the only way it could be anything other than the usual instance for `Either a` is if `return` gave you `Left foo` for some `foo.`  This though is impossible because of the other identity law: `return x >>= \y -> Right y = Right x`

Comment: @AndrewC to get an applicative with `Either` only requires a semi-group and not a monoid.  This is because `pure` does not have to use the identity.  Thus you have other instances, such as the one generated by `const`.  I think you might have even more instances than the obvious ones using this semi-group construction.

Comment: @PhilipJF Semigroup: oh yes, you're right - I was thinking of product rather than sum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Key idea

My understanding is that `Missing3` and `Unknown3` work a bit like `Nothing`, except they give a little more feedback about why there's no answer, so might behave slightly differently to each other. Certainly I think `Missing3` should behave like `Nothing`.

Let's look at how these are defined for `Maybe`:

### Functor

Here's the Functor instance for `Maybe`:

```
instance  Functor Maybe  where
    fmap _ Nothing       = Nothing
    fmap f (Just a)      = Just (f a)
```

I think it's clear how to deal with `Missing3` and `Unknown3` here.

### Monad

```
instance  Monad Maybe  where
    (Just x) >>= k      = k x
    Nothing  >>= _      = Nothing

    (Just _) >>  k      = k
    Nothing  >>  _      = Nothing

    return              = Just
    fail _              = Nothing
```

You can't help but do the same here with `>>=` for `Missing3` and `Unknown3`, since you don't have a value to bind with. The only question is do you fail with `Unknown3` or `Missing3`?

### Applicative

Here's where there's a little more digging:

```
instance Applicative Maybe where
    pure = return
    (<*>) = ap

ap                :: (Monad m) => m (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
ap                =  liftM2 id

liftM2  :: (Monad m) => (a1 -> a2 -> r) -> m a1 -> m a2 -> m r
liftM2 f m1 m2          = do { x1 <- m1; x2 <- m2; return (f x1 x2) }
```

Now that translates to

```
mf <*> mx = do
    f <- mf
    x <- mx
    return (f x)
```

Which you can use all the time to turn a Monad into an Applicative.

### Aside: Applicative is great.

In fact, whenever you find yourself writing

```
this thing = do
    something <- some monadic thing
    more <- some other thing
    yetmore <- another thing too
    return (combine something more yetmore)
```

you should rewrite it using applicative notation:

```
this thing = combine <$> some monadic thing 
                     <*> some other thing 
                     <*> another thing too
```

Comment: Now I am writing the instance under your suggest,                instance  Functor Maybe3  where
        fmap _ Missing3       = Missing3
        fmap f (Just3 a)      = Just3 (f a)
        fmap f Unknown3       = Unknown3
instance Monad Maybe3 where
    (Just3 a) >>= k = k a
    Missing3 >>= _ = Missing3
    Unknown3 >>= _ = Unknown3
        
    (Just3 _) >> k = k
    Missing3 >> _ = Missing3
        
    return = Just3
    fail _ = Unknown3     ,                                                            How could I using the Monad?

Comment: @Xie I think you missed out `Unknown3 >> _ = Unknown3`.

Comment: @Xie I don't understand your question "How could I using the Monad?". What would you like to do?

Comment: +10 for illustrating the connection between applicatives and monads in the ``Applicative is great`` aside.